# How can filter a join in subclass?

Tags: nhibernate, mapping

I have the following situation, i need to map some readonly properties from a view, but i need to join with a filter to have only the one i need in that case.

```
 <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="XX"
                   namespace="XXYY">
  <subclass name="B" 
            extends="P"
            discriminator-value="IS"
            dynamic-insert="true" 
            dynamic-update="true" 
            lazy="true">

    <join table="Aview" inverse="true">
      <key column="ID_A" />
      <property name="IdBlabla" insert ="false" update ="false" column="ID_BlaBla"/>
      <property name="Tipo" insert ="false" update ="false" />
      <many-to-one name="CC" column="ID_C" cascade="none" insert ="false" update ="false"/>
    </join>
      </subclass>

 </hibernate-mapping>
```

How can i filter for a particular ID_C ??

I need just one result from join, otherwise i have multiple objects

Comment: Your question is unclear, your join bring multiple results? Does it work correctly without the many-to-one? Particular ID_CC (ID_C?) hard coded to your mapping?

Comment: I need to have only the row with a particular ID_C in the view, I need to have a one to one mapping, the real situation is more complex but if i can set some dynamic filter on the joined table i hit the goal. otherwise when i getbyid i have multiple result.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a trick

I set the filter condition in key column field and it works!!!

```
<join table="Aview" inverse="true">
      **<key column="ID_A and ID_C=:MyFilter.IdCC" />**
      <property name="IdBlabla" insert ="false" update ="false" column="ID_BlaBla"/>
      <property name="Tipo" insert ="false" update ="false" />
      <many-to-one name="CC" column="ID_C" cascade="none" insert ="false" update ="false"/>
    </join>
```

Comment: Now i have a problem with alias in the query